# How to use date objects instead of date 'strings' and still achieve same result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this following schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema ({
    event: { 
            full: String,
            date: String,
            name: String,
    }
});
```

Examples of the values:

```
event.date = '16/02/2015' (DD/MM/YY)
event.name = 'Classic'
event.full = Concatenation of event.date and event.name = '16/02/2015 Classic'
```

This three are strings, and i need use object date in the event.date, in order to sort by date in my views.

My question is:

How can i use object date in the event.date, with this format? (DD/MM/YY).. and still achieve concatenate the event.date(object date) + event.name(string) in the event.full??

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Javascript `Date()` method to convert strings into Date objects.

```
var MySchema = new Schema ({

  var d = new Date('16/02/2015')
  //This returns a Date object: 16 February 2015 00:00:00 UTC.
  //You can now apply prototypal functions which belong to the Date() method.

  var datetime = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
  var eventName = "Classic";
  var fullName = datetime + " " + eventName;

  event: { 
          date: datetime,
          name: eventName,
          full: fullName
  }
});
```

You can then choose whether to use the `Date` object, or the concatenated String, at your leisure.

Another option is to use the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library, which specifically handles these types of situations.

Moment.js is used like this:

```
moment("20150216").format("MM/DD/YY");
```

[Javascript Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: I think i prefer using the Date() method. How about you?

Comment: I prefer it as well. As much as possible, I try to avoid adding any extra libraries or dependencies to my code. However, in a situation like yours, I'd say moment.js could make things easier, and doesn't weigh more than 12kb.